# information exchange

Tags: c#, .net

I need to pass information from one exe to another exe.  Is it possible ?

If it is possible, can you give me idea to solve this problem.

here i need to send some string msg to another exe  . the another exe should recive that msg and it should perform some operation depends on the that string msg...

Comment: Learn to think about the problem and clearly define it in your mind before you rush to ask a question. If you do not know how to ask questions, read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this is a number of ways, so just to name a few:

- Shared files
- A common database
- Remoting
- Sockets
- WCF

so you probably have to be a bit more specific. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: named pipes would be another way to add to your list

Answer (score 1):

> With program A:
>   Create a file.
>   Write your data in it
>   Close the file

---

> With program B:
>   While(file_in_use or empty) wait
>   Open the file
>   Read the data you need
>   Close the file

---

There is probably a better way to do this. Perhaps with sockets? This is just the only one I am remembering since I just woke up.

Comment: If you are doing it this way, you can always just use a file watcher and be notified when a file changes

Answer (score 0):

Remoting is what you need to be looking into though be aware that this strategy does differ in functionality between .Net 2.0 and .Net 3.0+.